# Python recursion local vs global

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on algos in python and tried to implement python sudoku solver. After many tries I've decided to look for the solution and decided to use the one listed [here](https://medium.com/daily-python/solving-sudoku-puzzle-using-backtracking-in-python-daily-python-29-99a825042e)

I've tried to play with the code and modify it to accept a local variable sudoku instead of the global one, however it seems like my code solves the sudoku and then replaces the solved sudoku with the unsolved one probably due to the recursion modification.

Here is my modified code:

```
#Forming the Puzzle Grid
def form_grid(puzzle_string):
    global grid
    print('The Sudoku Problem')
    for i in range(0, len(puzzle_string), 9):
        row = puzzle_string[i:i+9]
        temp = []
        for block in row:
            temp.append(int(block))
        grid.append(temp)    
    printGrid()
Function to print the Grid
#Function to print the grid

def printGrid():
    global grid
    for row in grid:
        print(row)

#Function to check if a digit can be placed in the given block
def possible(grid,row,col,digit):
    for i in range(0,9):
        if grid[row][i] == digit:
            return False
    for i in range(0,9):
        if grid[i][col] == digit:
            return False
    square_row = (row//3)*3
    square_col = (col//3)*3
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if grid[square_row+i][square_col+j] == digit:
                return False    
    return True

def solve(grid):
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            if grid[row][col] == 0:
                for digit in range(1,10):
                    if possible(grid, row,col,digit):
                        grid[row][col] = digit
                        solve(grid)
                        grid[row][col] = 0  #Backtrack step
                return grid

puzzle_string = "004300209005009001070060043006002087190007400050083000600000105003508690042910300"
solve(form_grid(puzzle_string))
```

Can't figure out how to modify the code to accept the sudoku as a parameter while returning the correct result, I've also tried to check for validity in every cal such as:

```
  if 0 not in grid.flatten():
        return grid
```

but that yielded the same result

Answer (score 1):

You could take the following steps:

- Remove the global variable and all `global` statements
- Turn your functions into methods of a new `Sudoku` class
- Make `from_grid` the constructor of that class, i.e. name it `__init__`
- Define `self.grid = []` in this constructor. This way `grid` is an *instance* member, so it is separate for each instance you create of `Sudoku`
- Remove all `grid` function parameters, but add `self` as the first parameter of all these methods, and make sure to reference `self.grid` where ever you need access to the grid
- `solve` has an algorithmic problem: it returns `grid` when it has already backtracked a working "move". Instead make `solve` such that it returns a boolean: `True` when the solution is found, and `False` if not, and make sure it does *not* clear any moves when a solution is found, and does not try any alternatives. That way `self.grid` will have the solution.

Here are those things implemented, with a few other cosmetic changes:

```
class Sudoku:
    def __init__(self, puzzle_string):
        self.grid = [
            list(map(int, puzzle_string[i:i+9]))
            for i in range(0, len(puzzle_string), 9)
        ]    

    #Function to print the grid
    def printGrid(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            print(row)

    #Function to check if a digit can be placed in the given block
    def possible(self, row, col, digit):
        if digit in self.grid[row]:
            return False
        for i in range(0,9):
            if self.grid[i][col] == digit:
                return False
        square_row = (row//3)*3
        square_col = (col//3)*3
        for i in range(0,3):
            for j in range(0,3):
                if self.grid[square_row+i][square_col+j] == digit:
                    return False
        return True

    def solve(self):
        for row in range(9):
            for col in range(9):
                if self.grid[row][col] == 0:
                    for digit in range(1,10):
                        if self.possible(row, col, digit):
                            self.grid[row][col] = digit
                            if self.solve():
                                return True
                            self.grid[row][col] = 0  #Backtrack step
                    return False
        return True

puzzle_string = "004300209005009001070060043006002087190007400050083000600000105003508690042910300"
puzzle = Sudoku(puzzle_string)
print('The Sudoku Problem:')
puzzle.printGrid()
puzzle.solve()
if puzzle.solve():
    print("Solved:")
    puzzle.printGrid()
else:
    print("Sorry, no solution found")
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you were assigning the current cell always back to `0` and checked all possible digits regardless of the result of the recursive `solve`. you should check if the recursive `solve` is valid and decide what would be the next step.

The following is a small fix to your code. First, `solve` should return `bool` (i.e., `True` or `False`) as the pointer to `grid` remains the same, so you ddon't really need to return it. Then you should use the recursive call to check if a valid solution was found. If not, continue to the next digit, and if you checked all digits, assign `0` back to the current cell and return `False`. Otherwise (if a valid solution was found) return `True`.

```py
def solve(grid):
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            if grid[row][col] == 0:
                valid = False
                for digit in range(1, 10):
                    if possible(grid, row,col,digit):
                        grid[row][col] = digit
                        if solve(grid):
                            return True
                
                grid[row][col] = 0  # Backtrack step
                return False

    return True

puzzle_string = "004300209005009001070060043006002087190007400050083000600000105003508690042910300"
grid = form_grid(puzzle_string)
printGrid()
solve(grid)
print()
printGrid()
```

BTW, there were few bugs in your code, such as relating to a global `grid` but not initializing it anywhere.

Also, `solve` is not very efficient as in each recursive call you are searching for the next empty cell. Currently is just a 9X9 grid, so it would be fast anyway, but for generalization, or just as a principal, a better way to use the recursive call is that `solve` would receive the `row` and `col` of the next position to check.

Finally, it might be better to remove the global grid and just return it from the `form_grid` function. the same for `printGrid` that should get the grid to print. The following is a version with the mentioned modifications:

```py
#Forming the Puzzle Grid
def form_grid(puzzle_string):
    grid = []
    print('The Sudoku Problem')
    for i in range(0, len(puzzle_string), 9):
        row = puzzle_string[i:i+9]
        temp = []
        for block in row:
            temp.append(int(block))
        grid.append(temp)
    return grid


#Function to print the grid
def printGrid(grid):
    for row in grid:
        print(row)

    print()


#Function to check if a digit can be placed in the given block
def possible(grid, row, col, digit):
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if grid[row][i] == digit:
            return False

    for i in range(0, 9):
        if grid[i][col] == digit:
            return False

    square_row = (row // 3) * 3
    square_col = (col // 3) * 3
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            if grid[square_row + i][square_col + j] == digit:
                return False

    return True


def get_next_position(current_row, current_col):
    if current_col == 8:
        if current_row == 8:
            return None, None

        return current_row + 1, 0

    return current_row, current_col + 1


def solve(grid, row, col):
    if row is None:
        return True

    next_row, next_col = get_next_position(row, col)

    if grid[row][col] != 0:
        return solve(grid, next_row, next_col)

    for digit in range(1, 10):
        if possible(grid, row, col, digit):
            grid[row][col] = digit
            if solve(grid, next_row, next_col):
                return True

    grid[row][col] = 0
    return False


puzzle_string = "004300209005009001070060043006002087190007400050083000600000105003508690042910300"
grid = form_grid(puzzle_string)
print("Initial grid")
printGrid(grid)
is_solved = solve(grid, 0, 0)
print(f"Solved: {is_solved}")
print("Solved grid")
printGrid(grid)
```